# How can I look at the current environmental variables that eclipse IDE is using?

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I know that I can just run a program with

```
System.out.println(System.getEnv());
```

but I would like to just check them without having to do that.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you mean opening a `cmd` and  using `set`?

Comment: I do not think Eclipse provide a facility to show its environment variables.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is actually a way to see the env vars. It is not implemented as a function, but part of other tasks.

You can right click on any projects in **Package Explorer**, then click

**Run As** -> **Run Configurations**. 
And here, in tab **Environment** -> **Select...**

Here you go. The list of system env Eclipse inherited are shown here.

Comment: This is awesome, great find!

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse's environment will inherit from the user executing it. Depending on your OS, you should have a command line tool to tell you.

You can also look at the configuration:

**Helios**

- *Help* menu -> *About Eclipse*
- *Installation Details* button
- *Configuration* tab

Comment: yea i know but i would like to get it from eclipse

Comment: This is a more comprehensive and direct solution. Technically this better qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @Grammin This *is* from Eclipse - "Helios" is a specific version of Eclipse. I can confirm this still works in Eclipse Neon.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you have Sysinternals Process Explorer installed - which I would strongly suggest any developer do - then you can:

1. Use the target icon (at the top of Process Explorer) and click on the Eclipse window which will select the Eclipse Process ID in the Process table
2. Right-click on the selected Eclipse entry and select Properties... from the context menu
3. Click on Environment

On Linux

1. If you need the PID, then use the following and click on the Eclipse window: `xprop | grep -i pid`
2. Replace `${PID}` with the PID of the Eclipse Process ID: `strings /proc/${PID}/environ`